# How to set the un-equipvalent ticks on axis

Tags: r, plot

I use the function `plot()` to draw a graph, like [my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj336.png):

[image: actual graph]

How do I change the scale on the *x-axis* of this graph? What I want is this plot [desired plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s5ON.png):

[image: expected graph]

Note that in the desired plot, the scale of large values has been "zoomed" out.

The following code doesn't work, because it can just change the tick on the axis, and it can't "zoom out" the scale of large values.

```
plot( ,xaxt="n")
axis(side = 1 , at = c(.....), labels=c(......))
```

Here is part of my dataset

```
>mydata$x
8030.476314, 8025.266041, 6550.710885, 5970.38876, 7264.607226, 
8105.388755, 631.6998778, 473.6989113, 434.0199707, 32448.60764, 
1287.084562, 6013.410273, 6022.650485, 5680.881734, 5749.552012, 
5885.51966, 6648.236012, 338.2700053, 3621, 16644.97723, 14300.96105, 
16137.212, 29490.37328, 6481.776993, 7268.522198, 7319.007536, 
5910.998347, 6533, 4114.221069, 5042.311631, 5037.559385, 5248.874105, 
5341.273234, 5351.568666, 5350.197626, 5403, 27171.96611, 25556.85006, 
1861.568555, 2264.092687, 2637.562323, 3505, 4246.485974, 4324.875638, 
4790.143909, 4884.720925, 4858.347495, 5034.098131, 759.6628005, 
737.7571713, 575.7047176, 797.4755344, 815.2221702, 934.3713607

> mydata$y
0.20355, 0.25855, 0.2045, 0.17305, 0.1853, 0.19565, 0.19155, 
0.18925, 0.18995, 0.17815, 0.18025, 0.09277798586, 0.1117, 0.1287, 
0.131, 0.14255, 0.1434, 0.22865, 0.2305, 0.21905, 0.21675, 0.21135, 
0.2058, 0.20925, 0.18565, 0.12515, 0.157, 0.14635, 0.15985, 0.20535, 
0.1632, 0.164766778365, 0.0702, 0.08465, 0.10045, 0.08295, 0.097, 
0.09065, 0.10305, 0.14659401364, 0.133299780225, 0.15775, 0.1511, 
0.1229, 0.14935, 0.1631, 0.18, 0.16755, 0.08455, 0.0826, 0.10935, 
0.11775, 0.1038, 0.11935, 0.114, 0.09783246265, 0.0806, 0.19775, 
0.12425, 0.1204, 0.10685, 0.11185, 0.10825, 0.1287, 0.1169, 0.1164, 
0.21265, 0.21555, 0.2395, 0.19205, 0.10138124242, 0.0944, 0.11605
```

Do anyone have idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: Do you wish to transform the underlying data or do you wish to change the visualization thereof? Merely messing around with the axis labels will (obviously) not be a viable solution. Could you give us some idea about the underlying data (e.g., post a few lines of it)?

Comment: Thank you @MichaelGruenstaeudl . I have updated my question and add part of the dataset.

Comment: Please provide your data using the output from `dput()` rather than copying the standard console output.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas. I didn't know this function. Now I have updated my question again.

Comment: @user5802211,  'x' and 'y' lengths differ? (I obviously second `dput()`)

Comment: Yes, but I figure out the answer now. That is to set the scale of the x-axis as log=x, but not setting the values as log scale.

Answer (score 0):

Would a log transformation be an acceptable solution? (code below)

Here's the raw data to the left and same data with a log transformation to the right

[image: same data with a log transformation]

```
df <- data.frame(y = c(0:6), x = c(0.01, 0.1, 0.9, 1, 25, 34.9, 56.2))
plot(df$x, df$y)

plot(log(df$x), df$y)
```

Comment: Thank you @Eric, but it is not desired. Please carefully check the desired plot :). As we can image that the range from 500 to 50000, if we want to show the tick mark of smaller value, like 500, 1000. These smaller values should be suppressed to the extremely left-hand side, but actualy it is not. The x-axis on the desired plot is what i am required to do, so log scale does not help.

Comment: I see. I'm still a bit confused by the gap between 2000 and 5000, it's obvious that it's truncated in some way, but you still have observations there. How does that work exactly? Would [`facet_wrap`/`facet_grid` from ggplot2](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/) be a way to solve this?

Comment: Thank you @Eric Fail.  I figure out the solution now. That is to set the scale of the x-axis as log=x, but not setting the values as log scale.

Comment: @user5802211, glad to hear you found a solution. I will encourage you to post your solution as an answer such that this question can be closed in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of this is to add l`og=x` to the `plot()` function to set the x-axis as log scale.